# Doctrine QueryBuilder multiple distinct

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, distinct

I would like to restrict results with `DISTINCT` on two columns using [doctrine ORM](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

My function is like this :

```
public function findFdvLinkedToPdv($pointVenteCodes){
    $queryBuilder = 
    $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
                ->leftJoin('r.forceVente', 'forceVente')
                ->leftJoin('r.pointVente', 'pointVente')
                ->leftJoin('r.signature', 'signature')
                ->leftJoin('signature.affaire', 'affaire')
                ->andWhere('pointVente.code IN (:pointvente_codes)')
                ->orderBy('forceVente.matricule', 'ASC')
                ->addOrderBy('pointVente.code', 'ASC')
                ->addOrderBy('affaire.code', 'ASC')
                ->addOrderBy('r.type', 'ASC')
                ->setParameters(array('pointvente_codes' => $pointVenteCodes,))
                ->select(array(
                        'forceVente.matricule AS forcevente_matricule',
                        'pointVente.code AS pointvente_code',
                        'affaire.code AS affaire_code',
                        'r.id AS id',
                        'r.profil AS profil',
                        'r.type AS type',
                        'forceVente.nom AS nom',
                        'forceVente.prenom AS prenom',
                        'forceVente.email AS email',
                        'r.deletedAt AS deletedAt'));
    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

For each forcevente.matricule and each pointVente.code , I have from 2 to 6 rows. I would like to get one row for each couple forcevente.matricule/pointVente.code I have to do a `distinct` on both columns, but when I try :

```
            ->select(array(
                    'DISTINCT forceVente.matricule AS forcevente_matricule',
                    'DISTINCT pointVente.code AS pointvente_code',
                    'affaire.code AS affaire_code', etc ...
```

I have a doctrine error ...

[EDIT]
I do this in PHP after executing the request to filter the results...

```
//BEGIN PATCH
$i=0;
$linkedForceVentes2 = array();
foreach ($linkedForceVentes as $item) {
    if (!isset($linkedForceVentes2[$item['pointvente_code']][$item['forcevente_matricule']])){
        $linkedForceVentes2[$item['pointvente_code']][$item['forcevente_matricule']] = $item;
    }else{
        unset($linkedForceVentes[$i]);
    }
    $i++;
}
//END PATCH
```

Comment: I don't know doctrine but in sql you use distinct on the entire select, so all of the returned fields must be unique. In your query it would just involve removing the second distinct.

Comment: The problem is that I have a createdAt, updatedAt, and deletedAt wich are always differents. So it keep returning me all the table.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. You can concatenate the first two fields together and then use distinct on these.

Comment: Yes I could. For now, I'm doing it in PHP after the request ... Durty, I am going to post it in a edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finaly resolved it with a groupBy :

```
->groupBy('forcevente_matricule', 'pointvente_code', 'type' , 'affaire_code');
```

Just after the select statement.